# ThreadPoolExecutor() errors in 1 machine but not in other

Tags: python, multithreading

The code is:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
...
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futh = [executor.submit(reports.fill, page) for page in pages]
    for data in as_completed(futh):
        df = df.append(data.result(), ignore_index=True)
```

On 1st machine the code run without any problem (Python 2.7.15).

On 2nd machine I get (Python 2.7.12):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 117, in <module>
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

For some reason The initialization of `ThreadPoolExecutor()` fails.
I tent to think that this might be a library version issue? But i'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass [max_workers](https://pythonhosted.org/futures/#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) parameter.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
```

Comment: I am aware of that but this is not mandatory to specify the max_workers. This example shows different setup http://elliothallmark.com/2016/12/23/requests-with-concurrent-futures-in-python-2-7/  I guess my question is what is the mandatory argument? and Where is the documentation of the changes between the two python versions? The offical docs doesn't even show support for this library with Python 2,7